# Days in ggplot graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I get days 1 to 365 on the x-axis? I need in particular that 365 is indicated as the final

```
ggplot(co21, aes(x = day2, y = cycle,  color = year, fill = year)) + geom_line() +
    labs(title = expression(paste(CO[2]," emission")),
         caption = "Source: NOAA Global Monitoring Laboratory",
         x = "Days",
         y = "Parts Per Millions")+
    theme_economist(base_size = 10))

head(co21)
  year month day  cycle  trend day2
1 2019     1   1 409.87 408.73    1
2 2019     1   2 409.89 408.73    2
3 2019     1   3 409.91 408.74    3
4 2019     1   4 409.93 408.75    4
5 2019     1   5 409.95 408.76    5
6 2019     1   6 409.98 408.76    6
```

This is the plot:
[image]

Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `scale_x_continuous` function since your x-axis is a continuous variable. The `breaks` parameter allow you to specify one of:

- `NULL` for no breaks
- `waiver()` for the default breaks computed by the transformation object
- A numeric vector of positions
- A function that takes the limits as input and returns breaks as output (e.g., a function returned by `scales::extended_breaks()`)

In our case, we would use the third option, specifying a vector of positions for the ticks. Your code to display a tick at every increment from 1 to the maximum amount of `day2` would hence be:

```
ggplot(co21, aes(x = day2, y = cycle,  color = year, fill = year)) + 
    geom_line() +
    labs(title = expression(paste(CO[2]," emission")),
         caption = "Source: NOAA Global Monitoring Laboratory",
         x = "Days",
         y = "Parts Per Millions") +
    theme_economist(base_size = 10)) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1,max(co21$day2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way. The trick is to specify `breaks`. See documentation.

```
df <- tibble(days = seq(1,365),y = rnorm(365))

ggplot(df,aes(days,y)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,365),
                     breaks = c(seq(0,365,25),365))
```